# How to select/find an element inside an event.currentTarget in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using this:

```
$('.sizeChart').on('vclick', '.entry .ui-btn', function(e){

        console.log( e )
        console.log( e.currentTarget )
        console.log( $( e.currentTarget )
        console.log( $( e.currentTarget ).find('input.qtyInput') )

    var qty = $( e.currentTarget ).find('input.qtyInput');
    // do something

 });
```

Which works, but `$( e.currentTarget ).find(...)` seems awkward to me.

I can't bind directly to the `input` because this binding will go dead on iOS3+4 after a couple of clicks. Binding to the closest `ui-btn` works throughout.

**Question:**
Is there a better/easier/faster way to do the binding than what I'm using ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `$(e.currentTarget)` IMO

Comment: Why you do the binding twice in nesting manner? Is that a typo?

Comment: *I can't bind directly to the input because this binding will go dead on iOS3+4 after a couple of clicks* `<-` I would recommend you try to find out why.

Comment: @FelixKling: I am at loss here... have not given up though. The function setting the binding runs, the selectors are correct, elements left and right and in the same scrollable area (like radio buttons) are working fine. The button works 3-4 times, then it's dead. On iOS I sometimes get an javascript execution timeout, but not consistently. Any ideas what else I could do to pin it down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `this` instead of `e.currentTarget`:

```
$(this).find(...);
```

[Proof that `event.currentTarget` and `this` are the same.](http://jsfiddle.net/xcEdG/)

Also the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) says:

> This property will typically be equal to the `this` of the function.

---

That's about it. It is pretty common to pass a DOM element directly to jQuery and use DOM traversal methods on it.